# Treat bash output from mysql db

Tags: mysql, bash, jenkins, nodes

i need to create script which will compare start time of VM and current time, and if the difference is greater than 50 minutes it will check if some jobs get this vm, if no than i will turn off it if yes, it will still work.

```
DB_USER='user'
DB_PASS='user'
DB='VM'
echo 'logging into db '$DB' as '$DB_USER''

####Check is there any free node in "VM_NUM table"####

get_time=$(/usr/bin/mysql -u $DB_USER   -p$DB_PASS $DB -e "SELECT VM_NAME,TIME from VM_LIST;")
echo $get_time
```

The following output:

```
VM_NAME TIME 3A1A 12:59:41 3A1D 12:54:36 NODE_3 00:00:00
```

So how to treat this output so it can be compared?

After --skip-column-names). Now i have got

```
for current_time in $(date +"%s")
do
    echo $current_time
get_time=$(/usr/bin/mysql --skip-column-names -u $DB_USER   -p$DB_PASS $DB -e "SELECT VM_NAME,TIME from VM_LIST;")
    echo $get_time

done
```

Output:

how to compare time?

Comment: Output is clear with 2 column name and their values. Each column is delimited by a space and each row is separated by space after two column values. Parse it accordingly.

Comment: i'am new in bash, help please

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do is to fetch unix timestamp from MyQSL using:

```
SELECT VM_NAME, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIME) from VM_LIST;
```

Then get the same from unix using:

```
date '+%s'
```

Now you can get the difference between 2 values and see of it is more than 50 minutes or not.

**PS:** You should also use `--skip-column-names` to skip column headers in output i.e.

```
mysql --skip-column-names -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB -e "SELECT VM_NAME,TIME from VM_LIST
```

Comment: Have updated workflow.thanks for  --skip-column-names

Comment: Another important thing is use of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIME)` for date/time comparison.